# ActiveRecord Join Query and select in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails 4 application, a client (clients table) can have many projects (projects table). I have a column called `name` in each table. I am trying to write a `join` and then `select` which uses projects as the base table and clients as the lookup table. `client_id` is the `foreign_key` in the projects table:

I am writing my query as follows:

```
Project.joins(:client).select('projects.id,projects.name,clients.name')
```

I get the following response:

```
Project Load (0.6ms)  SELECT projects.id,projects.name,clients.name FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "projects"."client_id"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Project id: 1, name: "Fantastico Client">]>
```

If I try to alias it like so:

```
Project.joins(:client).select('projects.id,projects.name,clients.name as client_name')
```

Then I get the following response:

```
Project Load (0.8ms)  SELECT projects.id,projects.name,clients.name as client_name FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "projects"."client_id"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Project id: 1, name: "The Dream Project">]>
```

In either case, ActiveRecord looses one of the names as you can see from the above response. How should I be writing this query?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If the column in `select` is not one of the attributes of the model on which the `select` is called on then those columns are not displayed.  All of these attributes are still contained in the objects within `AR::Relation` and are accessible as any other public instance attributes.

You could verify this by calling `first.client_name`:

```
Project.joins(:client)
       .select('projects.id,projects.name,clients.name as client_name')
       .first.client_name
```

Comment: If you do projects = Project.joins(:client).select('projects.id,projects.name,clients.name').  Then do project.first.attributes you'll see the missing columns.  Like Vee said it only shows the "Project" models records.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `:'clients.name'` as one of your symbols.  For instance:

```ruby
Project.select(:id, :name, :'clients.name').joins(:client)
```

I like it better because it seems like Rails understands it, since it quotes all parameters:

```sql
SELECT "projects"."id", "projects"."name", "clients"."name"
FROM "projects"
INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "projects"."client_id"
```

(I'm not 100% sure that's the exact SQL query, but I'm fairly certain and I promise it *will* use `"clients"."name"`)

Comment: I don't think this works because the SQL query doesn't have "as client_name" so "client.name" will override "project.name" attribute.

Comment: I think you have to qualify your columns if you have 2 tables with the same field name.  Otherwise you get an ambigous column error.    E.G. Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @MarkDavies if you are sure, I can change my answer.  Don't have a good Rails project to test it out on right now, but I think it does (surprisingly) work like I said.  Let me know!

Comment: Apologies Ryan, it does work but doesn't alias the columns.  I am using MySQL, Ruby 2 and Rails 4.2.  I tried it on a project using similar syntax (only had id as the same column in each table):  Contact.select(:id, :'contact_statuses.id').joins(:contact_status) which produced the SQL: SELECT `contacts`.`id`, contact_statuses.id FROM `contacts` INNER JOIN `contact_statuses` ON `contact_statuses`.`id` = `contacts`.`contact_status_id`.

Comment: @MarkDavies corrected it, but still haven't double checked it .  I'm assuming you're right, would make sense!

Answer (score 7):

To get both project table name and client name you can do like below query

`Project.joins(:client).pluck(:name,:'clients.name')`

Answer (score 5):

your query don't looses any thing. Actually you have applied join on models and you have written Project.joins(:client) that why it is looking like.
means It will hold Project related data as it is and associated data hold with alias name that you have given 'client_name' in your query.

if you use

```
Project.joins(:client)
   .select('projects.id project_id, projects.name projects_name,clients.name as client_name')
```

then it look like 
      [#, #]

but it hold all the attribute that you selected.

Comment: nice, adding .to_json makes that super clear.  I'd never have thought to check, since the data doesn't seem to be there otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
sql = Project.joins(:client).select(:id, :name, :"clients.name AS client_name").to_sql
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
  {"id"=>1, "name"=>"ProjectName1", "client_name"=>"ClientName1"},
  {"id"=>2, "name"=>"ProjectName2", "client_name"=>"ClientName2"}
]
```