# Selecting columns from included table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

given:

```
modelOne
    belongs_to :modelTwo
    field_one

modelTwo
    has_many :modelOnes
    field_two
```

how would I select both `field_one` and `field_two` using an `includes`

all of the answers I've found so far go along the lines of

```
modelTwo.includes(:modelOne).select(<:field_one, :field_two or 'model_twos.field_two, model_ones.field_one'>).references(:modelOne)
```

but all of them either give me an undefinedTable error on the included tables field or the results dont include the field on the included table

Comment: Did you visit this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312901/activerecord-join-query-and-select-in-rails)?

Comment: I sure did, it's not what i was looking for, I need the response from the query to be along the lines of [field_one, field_two],[field_one, field_two], etc

Comment: Do you have an instance of modelTwo already in memory, and you are looking for a method to invoke that will produce the array output you reference?  Or are you looking for a query that will accept (e.g.) a modelTwo ID and produce this output?

Comment: So, normally with the select it'd give: `<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<modelTwo :id , :field_two>, #<modelTwo :id , :field_two>, etc, etc]>` or thereabouts.

I would like to get a result like: `<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<modelTwo :id , :field_two, :field_one>, #<modelTwo :id , :field_two, :field_one>, etc, etc]>` or something similar. 

`select` looked perfect at first, but apparently it can't do what I need.