# query include methods rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a **Student** model and that model `has_many` subscriptions. I need to return all students who have subscriptions. this object must contain only the student's `name`, `email`, `phone` and `status`, in addition to the subscription `id` and `recurrence_code`. I thought something more or less like this but I can't succeed in the query:

```
 students = Student.all.includes(:subscriptions)
 students.each do |student|
  student.select(:id, :name, :email, :phone, :status,  subscription: {
    methods: [:id, :recurrency_code]}  
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic [inner join](https://www.ananunesdasilva.com/posts/understanding-activerecord-inner-joins) scenario

```rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
end
```

I find it helpful to break these problems into steps:

"Only Students where a Subscription record is present" is a standard inner join:

`Student.joins(:subscriptions).uniq`

"object must contain only the student's name, email, phone and status"

`Student.joins(:subscriptions).select(:name, :email, :phone, :status).uniq`

"in addition to the subscription id and recurrence_code"

```rb
students = Student.joins(:subscriptions)
                  .select(
                    'students.name, students.email,'\
                    'students.phone, students.status, '\
                    'subscriptions.id as subscription_id,'\
                    'subscriptions.recurrence_code as subscription_recurrence_code'
                  )
```

A few notes:

##### 1. Using `select` with `joins`

@vee's [SO Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312901/activerecord-join-query-and-select-in-rails) points out:

> If the column in `select` is not one of the attributes of the `model` on which the `select` is called on then those columns are not displayed. All of these attributes *are* still contained in the objects within `AR::Relation` and are accessible as any other public instance attributes.

This means if you load an individual record (e.g. `students.first`), you will only see the `Student` attributes by default. But you can still access the `Subscription` attributes by the `as` name you set in the query. E.g.:

`students.first.subscription_recurrence_code`

#### 2. Use `.uniq` to eliminate duplicates.

Because of the `has_many` relationship, the query `Student.joins(:subscriptions)` will return a record **for each subscription**, which means each student will appear in the result the same number of times as they have subscriptions. Calling `.uniq` (short for unique) will remove duplicates from the result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm agree with the Chiperific response, but I disagree to use the uniq method because it doesn't call the 'DISTINCT' in the SQL query.

> [Rails: uniq vs. distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575398/rails-uniq-vs-distinct)

For me it's better to use `distinct`. So the query could be as this:

```
Student.joins(:subscriptions).distinct.select(
  :name, :email, :phone, :status, 
  'subscriptions.id AS subscription_id',
  'subscriptions.recurrence_code'
)
```